# Prestashop Multi store set up

Tags: prestashop, multistore

I am using Prestashop 1.7 ( I don't think it will make much different from 1.6 ) I want to set up multistore across 2 different domains but they're hosted on the same server. How do I set up the 2nd site. Do I upload files to it or do I just leave it and it works automatically? Never done a multistore before.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to have two different VirtualHosts, one for each site. Every VirtualHost will be listening on a different domain name (same port) but will point to different directories. Also, you'll need to have two different databases, one for each of your sites

Apache Implementation

**Site 1**

```
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX>
    DocumentRoot "/www/html/site1"
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com

    # Other directives here ...

</VirtualHost>
```

**Site 2**

```
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX>
    DocumentRoot "/www/html/site2"
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com

    # Other directives here ...

</VirtualHost>
```